# The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large on IE while launching the application

Tags: tomcat, iis, internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2008, http-status-code-413

Can someone help me with this issue ?

This issue is persistent for few users while working for others . 
While they are launching the application they are facing this issue on IE , windows 2008 .**Error code is HTTP error code 413 .**

I checked the resolution but there are so many i am confused on whats the real root cause of this issue and what settings needs to be changed like in IIS or other config files .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since, the issue is persistent for few users. Perhaps the issue is related to the IE browser temporary internet files, cookies, cache, and history.

Try to refer to the following steps to clear browser data:

Open Internet Explorer-> Select 'Tools'-> 'Internet Options'-> Then select 'Delete' for  temporary internet files, cookies, and history -> Click Delete button to delete the data.

Comment: Thank you . yes tried doing that but no luck:( what else we can check here ?

Comment: whether this issue only occurs in IE browser or not? Try to use another browser to check it. Besides, please check the launch page, whether the request url contains too large entities or not? If you post enough code to reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: here is what i can see in logs : ] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1388): service failed, worker ajp13w is in local error state
service::jk_lb_worker.c (1407): unrecoverable error 413, request failed. Client failed in the middle of request, we can't recover to another instance.
 HttpExtensionProc::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2203): service() failed with http error 413

Comment: According to this log, it is still hard to find the real reason. Whether this issue only happens in Windows server 2008? Which version of IIS are you using?  Try to set the uploadReadAheadSize and requestLimits in applicationHost.config file on IIS. Reference: [Request Limits <requestLimits>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/)